# How can I configure Quarkus logging to TRACE only my "my.package" category?

Tags: quarkus

How can I configure Quarkus logging to get only trace/debug messages from a desired category?

Here is the properties that I tried so far:

```
-Dquarkus.log.level=TRACE
-Dquarkus.log.file.enable=true
-Dquarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/trace.log
-Dquarkus.log.file.level=TRACE
-Dquarkus.log.category."my.package".level=TRACE
```

This will print all trace messages plus my category.

If I remove `-Dquarkus.log.level=TRACE` no trace/debug messages are printed at all.

Ideas on how to configure it?

Comment: Can you please remove the irrelevant options as to make it more readable?

Comment: This might be a bug in quarkus, I'm looking into it

Comment: Do you mean that you see nothing in the log file or the console?

Comment: I meant there is no TRACE or DEBUG messages on file or console, only INFO messages if I remove the quarkus.log.level property.
I had the same behavior configuring the quarkus.log.console properties.

Comment: If I use `-Dquarkus.log.level=INFO` and `quarkus.log.category."org.acme.rest".level=DEBUG` then in my log file I can see the correct output. In the console I only see INFO

Comment: setting only -Dquarkus.log.level=INFO and -Dquarkus.log.category."my.package".level=TRACE I only got INFO on quarkus.log and console.

maybe you are using a different version? (0.11.0  here)

Comment: I opened this issue for the console: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1354

Comment: When I set `-Dquarkus.log.level=TRACE` I see a of ton stuff in `quakus.log`

Comment: Yes, with -Dquarkus.log.level=TRACE a lot of debug messages are printed, but so far still not able to trace only my custom category (file or console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand is that Quarkus uses various **miminum** logging levels.

There is a minimum logging level for the what get's logged in the console (`quarkus.log.console.level`), the minimum logging level for every log category `quarkus.log.level` and then if you setup a logging level for a category, you have that as well.

So if you want TRACE log messages to the console, you will need to set `quarkus.log.console.level=TRACE`.
If you don't do that, then the default level is `INFO` meaning that **nothing** below `INFO` will be logged even if the category is set. 
This setting is completely unrelated to the setting for logging to the file.