# Quarkus log level INFO in console and DEBUG in file

Tags: logging, quarkus

How can I tell Quarkus to log only messages with severity levels at least INFO in the console (to keep it clean) but log every messages with severity level at least DEBUG in a file?

I thought that writing the following in `application.properties` would do the job.

```
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.console.level=INFO

quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
```

As I understand from the [manual](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging) (and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069964)), this configuration should tell quarkus to set every category to DEBUG; but accept only INFO and higher levels in the console.

But it fails in a strange way. Quarkus indeed logs DEBUG and higher severity messages in a file, as expected, but it also logs *some* messages with DEBUG severity in the console.
Here is an example.

```
2022-03-25 21:19:17,858 DEBUG [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.2.0.Final
2022-03-25 21:19:19,526 DEBUG [org.hib.Version] (build-16) HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2022-03-25 21:19:21,935 DEBUG [org.hib.Version] (main) HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2022-03-25 21:19:21,969 DEBUG [org.hib.ann.com.Version] (main) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-25 21:19:22,224 DEBUG [org.hib.dia.Dialect] (main) HHH000400: Using dialect: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.dialect.QuarkusPostgreSQL10Dialect
2022-03-25 21:19:22,500 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (main) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class io.github.oliviercailloux.jquestions.MyApplication
2022-03-25 21:19:22,956 DEBUG [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.2.0.Final
2022-03-25 21:19:35,560 DEBUG [org.hib.tup.ent.EntityMetamodel] (main) HHH000157: Lazy property fetching available for: io.github.oliviercailloux.jquestions.entities.Question
2022-03-25 21:19:35,572 DEBUG [org.hib.tup.ent.EntityMetamodel] (main) HHH000157: Lazy property fetching available for: io.github.oliviercailloux.jquestions.entities.Answer
2022-03-25 21:19:58,217 INFO  [io.git.oli.jqu.Startup] (main) Loading at startup due to io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent@5c703860.
```

Is this a bug? Or, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Quarkus are you using?

Honestly, I can't see any changelogs directly connected with the trouble you described, however, 2.7.5.Final seems to behave as expected with the default Quarkus logging:

```java
// Some stuff above
    @GET
    @Path("/person")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getPerson(@Valid Person p) {
        Log.debug("Test Debug Message!");
        Log.info(p);
        return p;
    }
// some stuff below
```

With the properties as you mentioned:

```sh
quarkus.log.file.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.console.level=INFO
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
```

Results in

1. Console one:
   [image]
2. Log file one:
   [image]

Comment: I use Quarkus 2.7.5.Final as well. Here is an [example application](https://github.com/oliviercailloux/JQuestions/tree/logs) that produces the behavior that I described. Make sure you are in the branch `logs` and run `mvn clean quarkus:dev` to see it. Maven prints DEBUG logs to the console, for example, `2022-03-31 19:02:58,115 DEBUG [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final`.